# Accessing script component right after instantiation

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine

I have a script creating UI buttons in Unity. It creates instances of a prefab, which has also custom script components in it. I'd like to instantiate a new copy and immediately access values members/fields of the newly created object's scripts:

```
turretButtons.Add(Instantiate(buttonProto, gameObject.transform));
turretButtons[turretButtons.Count - 1].image.sprite = turretIcon;
turretButtons[turretButtons.Count - 1].GetComponent<DetailsWindowController>().turretDefinition = turretDef;
```

The first line creates the new instance, the second change the icon, both work perfectly. The third however, in which I try to access the `DetailsWindowController` script/class's `turretDefinition` public member throws "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object". What am I missing?

Comment: can you include what the types are of turretButtons and buttonProto

Comment: Yeah, I know it's basic, but can you include inspector screenshots showing how these are set up?  Specifically that the buttonProto prefab does have a DetailsWindowController attached?

Comment: You are missing a reference. That is what the error message is telling you. Generally you shouldn't chain GetComponent() with member access without checking for Null references.

Comment: Are you sure that the `DetailsWindowController` is on the same GameObject and not maybe deeper in the hierarchy? You could try `GetComponentInChildren<DetailsWindowController>(true)` instead. Btw it would be a bit smarter to do `var newButton = Instantiate ...` and use `newButton` instead of `turretButtons[turret buttons.Count-1]` and add it to the list after you are done setting values ;)

Comment: @ryeMoss it has to be `Button buttonProto` and `List<Button> turretButtons` otherwise the first and second line would already throw compiler errors.

Comment: @derHugo: you are right, I had to replace `GetComponent<>` by `GetComponentInChildren<>` and now it works. If you post it as an answer, I'm happy to mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component you are looking for is probably not attached to exactly the same `GameObject` the `Button` component is attached to.

You should use [GetComponentInChildren](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInChildren.html) in order to always look for the component recursive downwards inside of the button's hierachy. Also note the `true` parameter which is required to find components on disabled children. This might be usefull in the case the button is spawned disabled.

```
var newButton = Instantiate(buttonProto, gameObject.transform);

newButton.image.sprite = turretIcon;
newButton.GetComponentInChildren<DetailsWindowController>(true).turretDefinition = turretDef;

turretButtons.Add(newButton);
```